# A simple .NET application run slowly than a similar environments

Tags: .net, performance, compare, production-environment

I was having difference execution performance in my ASP.NET app in various environments. So I decided realize some tests to verify what are the problem.

I simplified to a console application that do math calcs. No Network, no disk access, only math processing. To my surprise I got a stark difference in result times. I did the test in similar physical enviroments.

These were the results:

Enviroment A
[image: The slowly enviroment]

Enviroment B
[image: The faster enviroment]

Note that the difference betwen this enviroments is always greater than 100%.

I already checked the environments, uninstalled Hyper-V, ran the process as administrator and high priority. No antivirus installed. The results were always the same.

What might be affecting performance in "Environment A"?

This is the app source code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityBoostEnabled = true;
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest;            

        PrintInfra();
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to start...");
        Console.ReadKey();

        Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("LOGARITHM TEST");
        Console.WriteLine($"    Round 1: {testeLog10()}");
        Clear();
        Console.WriteLine($"    Round 2: {testeLog10()}");
        Clear();
        Console.WriteLine($"    Round 3: {testeLog10()}");

        Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("FIBONACCI TEST");
        Console.WriteLine($"    Round 1: {testeFibonacci()}");
        Clear();
        Console.WriteLine($"    Round 2: {testeFibonacci()}");
        Clear();
        Console.WriteLine($"    Round 3: {testeFibonacci()}");

        Console.WriteLine("End of test");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string testeLog10()
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        var a = .0;
        for (double i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            a += Math.Log10(i);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        return string.Format($"{watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    }

    public static string testeFibonacci()
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        var a = .0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            a += Fibonacci(i);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        return string.Format($"{watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    }

    public static void Clear()
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: JIT has its freedom to compile IL to machine code. If you know how to use debugging tools such as WinDbg you might dump the true instructions executed and compare at that level.

Comment: Not answerable unless you send me those machines first...   And it has very little to do with ASP.NET performance

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Realy it's not ASP.NET fault. I reduced complexity of app to determine what are the problem of performance

Comment: @LexLi With the same .NET framework, same processor, can JIT compile different IL? Anyway I'll learn WinDbg to compare, thank you

Comment: @DiegoTroitiño JIT can possibly generate different "machine code" from the same "IL".